# Merge Dataframe and Retain Shape

Tags: python, merge, jupyter

I am attempting to merge the following data frames on policy number. Prior to merging, I have removed duplicates.

```
DF1 :

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 36368 entries, 0 to 36367
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
 0   PolicyNumber         36368 non-null  object 
 1   DriverNumber         36368 non-null  int64  
 2   AbilitecContactID    36368 non-null  object 
 3   AbilitecHouseholdID  36368 non-null  object 
 4   DriverCount          36368 non-null  int64  
 5   ClaimCount           36368 non-null  float64
 6   TotalPaid            36368 non-null  float64


DF2:
nt64Index: 9780 entries, 0 to 111118
Data columns (total 16 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype          
---  ------              --------------  -----          
 0   ClaimNumber         9780 non-null   object         
 1   AtFaultDescription  9780 non-null   object         
 2   ClaimStatus         9780 non-null   object         
 3   ClaimType           9780 non-null   object         
 4   DateOfLoss          9780 non-null   datetime64[ns] 
 5   DriverID            9780 non-null   int64          
 6   LossState           9780 non-null   object         
 7   PolicyNumber        9780 non-null   object         
 8   PolicyStateCode     9780 non-null   object         
 9   SubrogrationFlag    9780 non-null   object         
 10  TermEffectiveDate   9780 non-null   datetime64[ns] 
 11  VehicleID           9780 non-null   int64          
 12  ClaimTransPaidLoss  9780 non-null   float64        
 13  ClaimTransCount     9780 non-null   int64          
 14  DaysToClaim         9780 non-null   timedelta64[ns]
 15  DaysToClaim_h       9780 non-null   int32
```

My goal is to have a merged DF with **39,099 values for all fields except DateOfLoss and TermEffectiveDate.** Instead, I have the output below using a left merge on PolicyNumber.

```
Current output:
nt64Index: 39099 entries, 0 to 39098
Data columns (total 22 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype          
---  ------               --------------  -----          
 0   PolicyNumber         39099 non-null  object         
 1   DriverNumber         39099 non-null  int64          
 2   AbilitecContactID    39099 non-null  object         
 3   AbilitecHouseholdID  39099 non-null  object         
 4   DriverCount          39099 non-null  int64          
 5   ClaimCount           39099 non-null  float64        
 6   TotalPaid            39099 non-null  float64        
 7   ClaimNumber          9780 non-null   object         
 8   AtFaultDescription   9780 non-null   object         
 9   ClaimStatus          9780 non-null   object         
 10  ClaimType            9780 non-null   object         
 11  DateOfLoss           9780 non-null   datetime64[ns] 
 12  DriverID             9780 non-null   float64        
 13  LossState            9780 non-null   object         
 14  PolicyStateCode      9780 non-null   object         
 15  SubrogrationFlag     9780 non-null   object         
 16  TermEffectiveDate    9780 non-null   datetime64[ns] 
 17  VehicleID            9780 non-null   float64        
 18  ClaimTransPaidLoss   9780 non-null   float64        
 19  ClaimTransCount      9780 non-null   float64        
 20  DaysToClaim          9780 non-null   timedelta64[ns]
 21  DaysToClaim_h        9780 non-null   float64
```

Is this possible without filling everything with non-nulls? It sounds funny, but while running additional analysis, I noticed my merged df was the shape I was looking for but lost the change after rerunning.

Not an expert, thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Where does 39,099 come from when the original DFs have 36,368 and 9,780?